# Git: Hash values of files including changed and not staged ones in directory of working tree as a list

Tags: git

A simple scenario. I have two files test1 and test2. Committed both files.

I can see hash values in repo using `ls-tree` and hash values in staging/index using `ls-files --stage`.

Now I make a change in test1 and as expected hash value changes
I can see that hash value of "test1" using `hash-object`

As I see from **ls-files** documentation [git ls-files](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files)

**git ls-files just *outputs the filenames unless --stage is specified* in which case it outputs**

So my question is how can I see is the list of hash objects for corresponding files in a directory even for **changed files** which ***are yet to be staged***

A simple shell script would do. just wanted to know if there is an existing git command

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the hash that an object will have if you `git add` it using this:

```
git hash-object -t blob somefile.txt
```

You can list multiple files, or you can:

```
git hash-object -t blob --stdin-paths < some_list_of_files.txt
```

`git help hash-object` provides more details.

`hash-object` is considered part of the `git` "plumbing" - intended to be used by `git` itself and maybe by utility scripts, not particularly for end-user use (probably because it's not entirely clear how useful it is for someone to know the potential hash of an object that may or may not ever get committed to the database...).